# Consulta não ordena os registros por Asc/Desc

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho uma tabela chamada **cadcha (cadastro de chamada)** no banco de dados onde são guardadas todas as ligações realizadas pelos funcionários de uma determinada empresa.

```
cadcha
--------------------------------------------------
nreg    |telefone      |telpretot    |ramaldestino
1110     35420000       0,79          5065
```

telpretot = valor da ligação

Realizei uma consulta que traz a moda estatísca pelo valor das ligações, e precisava que a mesma fosse ordenada pela quantidade decrescente, ou seja, o registro com a quantidade maior, vem primeiro.

```
SELECT COUNT(telpretot) AS qtde, 
(CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0))) as       preco
FROM cadcha
WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015'
GROUP BY (CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0)))
ORDER BY qtde DESC;
```

Está funcionando ok, porém é retornado o registro ordenado do menor para o maior. Já tentei alterar o DESC para ASC mas o resultado exibido é o mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso corrigir o script para que os registros sejam ordenados do maior para ao menor?

Comment: tira o group by e tenta de novo.

Comment: qual o tipo do campo `telpretot` ?

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque a coluna **qtde** esta sendo preenchida no tempo de execução, pelo fato de você esta usando `COUNT(telpretot)`, tente dessa forma.

```
declare @cadcha table
(
  nreg int,
  telefone int,
  telpretot numeric(18,2),
  ramaldestino int,
  teldata date

)

insert into @cadcha values
(1110,     35420000 ,      0.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      0.3   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      0.5   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      5.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      6.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      10.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      110.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      32.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      32.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      34.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015'),
(1110,     35420000 ,      44.79   ,       5065, '08/03/2015')

select * from 
(
    SELECT COUNT(telpretot) AS qtde, 
    (CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0))) as       preco
    FROM @cadcha
    WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015'
    GROUP BY (CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0)))
)D
ORDER BY qtde DESC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rodou de boa, porém ele continua ordenando apenas do menor para o maior.

Comment: você pode posta seus dados do select sem o group by  só os dados do  `SELECT telpretot AS qtde, 
(CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0))) as preco
FROM cadcha
WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015 `

Comment: @antunesleo_ fiz um teste utilizando o `sql server` e não tive esse problema, talvez o banco de dados que você esta usando possa ter alguma implicação para não estar ordenado da forma que você quer.

Comment: Também desconfio que seja algum problema com o SBDB (firebird) ou alguma limitação do mesmo, pois quando eu mando a query ordenar pelo campo `preco` tanto ASC/DESC funcionam, porém pelo campo `qtde` ele sempre volta ordenado do menor para o maior. De qualquer forma, a ajuda de vocês abriu minha cabeça para outra lógica que deu certo aqui, obrigado pelo a ajuda!

Comment: @antunesleo_ o campo telpretot é de que tipo?:

Comment: tipo `DOUBLE PRECISION`

Comment: você já tentou retira o `CAST` do campo `telpretot` para ver como ele se comporta?

Comment: Descobri onde estava o problema. No sistema quando se está logado como ADM, tem uma tela onde podemos executar scripts SQL e estava realizando todos os testes por lá. Fiz um teste utilizando o IBExpert e o resultado veio ordenado do maior para o menor, como eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

E esse group by ai, remove ele

```
SELECT COUNT(telpretot) AS qtde, 
(CAST(telpretot AS DECIMAL(18,0))) as preco
FROM cadcha
WHERE teldata = '08/03/2015'
ORDER BY qtde DESC;
```

Comment: Eu preciso do group by na query para agrupar por valor, exemplo, agrupo todas as ligações de 1 real e quanto quantas ligações. Agrupo ligações de 2 reais e conto quantas ligações. Teria alguma forma de ordenar isto com o group by?